# How to start developing with Microsoft MapPoint?

Tags: mappoint

How to start developing with Microsoft MapPoint? I need to make a simple app
that will use the MapPoint web service, so it is an online rather than an offline
app which would use an ActiveX control in C# for example.

I can't find the SDK for download. There are few on Microsoft's site but they
are old, something like 2001 and 2002.

Please give me some advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MapPoint Web Service was discontinued about two years ago. If you want an online solution, look at the various Bing Maps products/services which include AJAX and web services, and replaced MWS.

The MapPoint desktop product remains in production. Documentation for 2013 is online and ships with the application. It has an ActiveX control but this is not suitable for Internet applications because each user would require a licensed copy of MapPoint installed on their machine. In an Intranet it is possible to do this, but generally it is not practical for the Internet.